# Cocos2d-x heap corruption detected by tmalloc_large

Tags: c++, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

i can't find any solution for this problem:

```
libc(7095): heap corruption detected by tmalloc_large
```

i'm developing a sample game based on cocos2d-x (c++/ndk) , and  can't find reason for this problem ?
what are possible reason for this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just upgraded my NDK to android-ndk-r10d and got rid of this crash.

Comment: i solved this issue some how....i m using NDK-9c ... maybe add retain object in static create  method  and call release after did the job   ...i 'm also using physics in some scene , but that wasn't the cause of the problem ... thank for your answer.(vote +1 for participation ) :)